# Adding new elements to a List in C# is changing the elements added before

Tags: c#, arrays, list, vector

everybody!

I have a double[] array, called weights_c1 that assigns different values in each iteration of a for.
I also have a List, called wc1, to store the vector weights_c1 in each loop. 
So, I do:

```
wc1.Add(weights_c1);
```

The problem is that this way, the program changes the values of the element added to the list before.

Ex:
in the first iteration I have

```
wc1[0] = {1.0, 3.4, 2.2}
```

when the second iteration goes on with `wc1[1] = {2.0, 4.5, 1.0}`, the elements of wc1[0] also assume the same values `{2.0, 4.5, 1.0}`, and this happens after and after until the end of the loop.

The program is "linking" the current values of weights_c1 and automatically updating the values added to the list before.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It would really have help if you'd shown the code, but I'm 99.9% sure that you're just adding the reference to the same array multiple times. Remember that arrays are reference types - a `List<double[]>` contains *references* to array objects. If the list contains the same reference multiple times, then yes, you'll see the same elements...

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Thanks, everybody!
The suggestion from dasblinkenlight has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see this problem is that you are adding the same array object `weights_c1` to the list. Since arrays are reference types, a `List<double[]>` stores the reference to the array, not its copy. Any modifications that you make to the array after inserting it to the list are "visible" in the array that is currently stored in the list, because it is the same array object.

You can solve this by inserting a copy of your array into the list, like this:

```
double[] copy = new double[weights_c1.Length];
weights_c1.CopyTo(copy, 0);
wc1.Add(copy);
```